# How I can use in C# for Excel, the function Replace with the function Formula

Tags: c#, excel, excel-formula

I could find the solution for this!

I have a project in C# that change some cells from excel file.

So, I try to do this:

```
range = sheet.UsedRange;
// leer las celdas
int rows = range.Rows.Count;
int cols = range.Columns.Count;

Excel.Range startCell = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
Excel.Range endCell = sheet.Cells[rows, cols];
sheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Formula.Replace(@"C:\", @"C:\Gestion\");
```

But, I can't use the function Formula in the last line.

this line is wrong : `sheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Formula.Replace(@"C:\", @"C:\Gestion\");`

The right is `sheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Replace(@"C:\", @"C:\Gestion\");`

But now, I have another problem. The program doesn't change all cells. Only change one cell when the function find this string @"C:\"

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to reassign the formula to the range:

```
sheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Formula = sheet.Range[startCell, endCell].Formula.Replace(@"C:\", @"C:\Gestion\");
```